# Not sure if connected or not. 16.0.4

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, internet, connection

I have an issue and it's giving me crazy, I've installed the 17.10 ubuntu version on my Laptop "Dell Inspiron N4110" and everything was great until my internet connection sudenly gone. Actually I don't have internet yet in my house because of my ISP problem.
So my neighbor gaves me his wifi password, well my surprise is, with windows 10 works perfect but ubuntu doesn't. I decided to remove the 17.10 version and installed OpenSuse.. Same, removed OpenSuse and installed a 16.04 LTS version of ubuntu... Surprise! the same.
So i made a search on internet but i don't know how to make the search because, the wifi connects but there's not internet and it's confusing.
I made some pings in console in both systems "windows and ubuntu" and this is the result. With same wifi network..

[image: ping with windows 10]

[image: ping with ubuntu]

What can i do? I want to keep working with ubuntu but i can't without connection. Thank you in advance

Update

Terminal result after run `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A301` command

```
juanr@juanr:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A301
:00.0 Network controller [0280]: 
Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:008a](rev 34)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 BGN [8086:5325]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the result of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

Comment: Already edited my question with the results @JonasCz

Comment: Try this (2nd post): https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2042332&highlight=11n_disable  any change ?